# Not able to install Nuget Package WindowsAzure.Storage in my project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, azure-storage, nuget-package

I am having WebAPI project which wants to use Azure Storage. So, I tried to add nuget package  WindowsAzure.Storage both the way using Package Manager Console and Finding from Manage nuget package. Both the way doesn't work for me. Is it Nuget manager production issue?

It is giving me the below error when I tried to install via PM Console :

[image]

Please advise is it the issue with my visual studio/nuget package/azure sdk or something else??

Note: I am using VS Ultimate 2013. (I have also tried in VS 2015 Preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have restricted your package sources. At the top of the Package Manager Console window, there is a Package Source drop-down. You should have "All" or "nuget.org" selected, and "nuget.org" available.

If "nuget.org" isn't in the drop down, you'll need to click the gear icon to the right of the drop-won and make sure you have the following checked (or add it if it isn't there):

[image: nuget.org]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me. I was making very silly mistake. It should be attached inbuilt with Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check that your nuget package manager is upto date. In my case i had to update the nuget package manager to resolve this issue.

Cheers